# What's the difference between そして and そうして?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between そして and そうして? Both mean 'and', 'and then' and are written with the same kanji. そして I've seen more often in texts, but そうして - only a couple of times. Is the difference only in frequency of usage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of そうして](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18066/meaning-of-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6)

Comment: No, it doesn't. In that answer is explained the difference between そうして and こうして. My question is not about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そうして means *in that way, as such, like that,...* in English.

例文：
どうぞ、そうしてくだ下さい。
Yes, please do it so.

Synonyms for そうして is そのようにして.

そして was originally shortened form of そうして,

but in the present Japanese, そして has become conjunction.

**そして cannot be used like そうして.**

そして　means *and, and then, thus,...* in English.

例文：　僕は宿題をしました。そして、買い物をしました。
I did my homework. And then, I went shopping.

[image]

This is already answered question on Hinative.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots, please explain the phrases in your own words. Also please do not promote other sites. I linked you to this site's tour and help center, please take a look at my comments yesterday.